# css: strike out text based on input

Tags: css

To display a task list where the entries with ticked checkbox are strikethrough, where the html is provided by an app (ia writer) and not changeable by the user, how to select the item in css? e.g. for the example below, `test checked` should be strikethrough, while `testing` is to be left as-is.

```css
input:checked~.task-list-item {
  text-decoration: line-through
}
```

```html
<li class="task-list-item">
<input type="checkbox" class="task-list-item-checkbox" disabled="" checked="">
test checked
</li>

<li class="task-list-item">
<input type="checkbox" class="task-list-item-checkbox" disabled="">
testing
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to use labels for the checkboxes?  You can do it like this:

```css
input:checked + label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<li class="task-list-item">
<input type="checkbox"  name="box1" class="task-list-item-checkbox" disabled="" checked="" >
<label for="box1">test checked</label>
</li>

<li class="task-list-item">
<input type="checkbox" name="box2" class="task-list-item-checkbox" disabled="">
<label for="box2">testing</label>
</li>
```

Edit: Here is the jS solution:

```js
var cboxs = document.getElementsByClassName("task-list-item-checkbox");
    for(var i = 0; i < cboxs.length; i++){
   
       if (cboxs[i].checked) {
            cboxs[i].closest(".task-list-item").style.textDecoration = "line-through";  
        }
    }
```

```html
<li class="task-list-item">
<input type="checkbox" class="task-list-item-checkbox" disabled="" checked="">
test checked
</li>

<li class="task-list-item">
<input type="checkbox" class="task-list-item-checkbox" disabled="">
testing
</li>
```

Comment: thanks, but that's sort of the problem: the html part is dynamically generated by a markdown editor within the app, and I cannot really customized the html part, only the css part.

Comment: @egwenesedai I don't believe you are able to style the parent element of the checkbox based on its checked status with only CSS.  Are you able to use JavaScript?

Comment: @egwenesedai I have updated my answer with a js solution.  Please take a look